# Cancel Button in UISearchController

Tags: uitableview, cancel-button, uisearchcontroller

In my project I'm using a `UITableViewController` with an internal `UISearchController` to filter the data in my `tableView`.

I have no problem to filter the data but I need to make a date of my `tableView` reload when I click on the **CANCEL** button `UISearchController` but I can not find the delegate method for this ...

Can you help me understand how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You need to set the `UISearchController` `searchBar's` `delegate`. Once you have done this, the addition of the delegate method `searchBarCancelButtonClicked:` will properly be called.

```
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
}
```

Comment: A little explanation would be nice!

Comment: @G.Samaras This is a delegate method of SearchBar ... The searchController directly using the searchbar delegate, so just call UISearchBarDelegate within the file header and delegate the searchbar (self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;) in viewDidLoad or other method used in the implementation file ... Then you can 'call the code inside the delegate method of SearchBar searchBarCancelButtonClicked and inside specify the function that should run the cancel Button.

Answer (score 21):

If you implement `UISearchResultsUpdating` protocol, you can know that cancelled is triggered when `active` is `false`.

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    if !searchController.isActive {
        print("Cancelled")
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want to dismiss here, do it async

Answer (score 3):

Swift 5

```
searchBar.delegate = self
.......

extension YourClass: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar){} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

searchController.searchBar.delegate = self


extension SearchViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar){} 
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.